# How to prevent modals in Bootstrap 5 from blocking the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

Whenever I open a modal, it prevents clicking on the rest of the page until it's gone, even when it doesn't have the visible background overlay. I've searched around for this, and found a lot of answers, but none of them seem to apply to bootstrap 5. Or if they do, they don't work. Here's what I've tried:

- `data-backdrop="false"`
- `data-bs-backdrop="false"`
- `role=menu`
- `var modal_5 = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('reward_5_modal'), {backdrop: false});`
- After showing the modal: `$('.modal-backdrop').removeClass("modal-backdrop");`

But no matter what, even without the dark background, I can't click on the rest of the page until it's gone. Here's the modal in question:

```
<div class="modal"
    role = "menu" 
     id="reward_5_modal"
     tabindex="-1"
     aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true"
     data-bs-backdrop="false"
     data-mdb-keyboard="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's not a whole lot going on here that it could be negatively interacting with. How can I stop it from disabling the rest of the page?

Comment: `$('.modal-backdrop').css('pointer-events', 'none');` maybe could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want the Bootstrap modal to be non-blocking, allowing users to interact with the underlying content while the modal is still open.

From Bootstrap 5 onwards, the way the modal works has been slightly changed compared to previous versions. The modal itself doesn't block the background from being clicked. Instead, it places a backdrop over the entire window which captures all clicks and stops them from reaching the content beneath.

Here's how you can make the modal non-blocking:

First, you correctly added data-bs-backdrop="false" to your modal. This prevents the dark backdrop from appearing.

However, even with the backdrop not showing, Bootstrap still stops click events from reaching elements beneath the modal. You can solve this by setting the modal's CSS pointer-events to none, and then setting pointer-events back to auto on the actual modal content so you can still interact with the modal

```
.modal {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-dialog {
    pointer-events: all; /* or just use auto */
}
```

Be aware: With the above setup, if a user clicks outside the modal, it won't automatically close. If you want the modal to close when clicking outside of it, you'll have to add a bit of JavaScript to do so

```
document.querySelector('.modal').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('reward_5_modal'));
    modal.hide();
});
```